# Using javascript to get the values of multiple fields and add them to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a script that takes the values of the fields and places them into a table for verification.  The thing is though, the user is able to add multiple fields(up to 5) and each field has its own id.  So, when a user inputs the values I want my script to take all the values from that field(even if they've added) and pass them into the table.  How would I go about doing this?
**User adds one 'set', clicks add chart**
[image: User adds one 'set']

**User adds another 'set'(up to 5).**
[image: Adds another set]

**When the user has added all the 'sets' he/she wants, They appear in the Jeppeson Charts section.**
[image]
**I need to get these values**

```
<div id="charts">
    <h3>Jeppeson Charts</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Airport Identifier</label>
        <input type="text" name="air_id_1" id="air_id_1" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Chart Identifier</label>
        <input type="text" name="chart_id_1" id="chart_id_1" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Chart Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="chart_desc_1" id="chart_desc_1" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Allows the user to add up to 5 different charts.**

```
var jep_num = 1;
    $("#add_chart").on("vclick", function(ev){
        jep_num += 1;
        if(jep_num <= 5){
            $("#charts").append("<fieldset><input type='text' name='air_id_" +jep_num +"' id='air_id_" +jep_num +"' /></fieldset><fieldset style='margin-left: 0.45%'><input type='text' name='chart_id_" +jep_num +"' id='chart_id_" +jep_num +"' /></fieldset><fieldset style='margin-left: 0.4%'><input type='text' name='chart_desc_" +jep_num +"' id='chart_desc_" +jep_num +"' /></fieldset>").trigger("create");
        }
        ev.preventDefault();
    })
```

**Table where the charts need to be added**

```
<div class="full">
    <div class="header">JEPPESON CHARTS</div>
</div>
<div class="half">
    <div class="half">
        <div id="air_id_field" class="table_field"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <div id="chart_id_field" class="table_field"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="half">
    <div class="full">
        <div id="chart_desc_field" class="table_field"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope I made sense with my rambling.  If not, let me know and I'll try to clarify.  I also know how to do this using MySQL and PHP, and I was hoping to avoid doing so with this particular feature.  But, if I need to I will.

Comment: is your question how to get the values of multiple fields and add them to the table?

Comment: Yes.  I had a slight laspe in thinking ability and apparently couldn't express that correctly.  Thank you, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you please show a sample HTML of the fields you need to get the values from?

Comment: Yes sir, I'll add it to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a class to each field and the added ones too. Also you need to wrap all three related fieldset in one div.

```
<div id="charts">
     <h3>Jeppeson Charts</h3>

    <div class="charts-fieldset">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Airport Identifier</label>
            <input class="air-input" type="text" name="air_id_1" id="air_id_1" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Chart Identifier</label>
            <input class="chart-input" type="text" name="chart_id_1" id="chart_id_1" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Chart Description</label>
            <input class="chart-desc-input" type="text" name="chart_desc_1" id="chart_desc_1" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can go through all of your sets one by one and get the values like that and then do what you want with them:

```
$('.charts-fieldset').each(function () {
    var air = $('.air-input', $(this)).val();
    var chart = $('.chart-input', $(this)).val();
    var chartDesc = $('.chart-desc-input', $(this)).val();
});
```